# Excel column entries modification

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have a big Excel file containing a column where I have entries of the type

```
A3F44
```

and I would like to transform them into

```
A3F4 - 4
```

in order to match them with the entries in another file. Since the file is big, I do not want to do it by hand.

How can I transform this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're all exactly five characters, and you always want the dash between the fourth and fifth characters, the following should work.

Assuming your data starts at A2, and you want the transformed data in column B, here's the formula to start you off in B2.

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(A2,4)," - ",RIGHT(A2,1))
```